# actions on codenameone, build error (part2)

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I'm on codenameone again, I added other actions to the buttons of an app, while launching the preview I get this:

"
Netbeans reports another issue right now:
I added other actions to buttons and now I'm getting the following error while launching the preview:

ant -f (file name)
-Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
No GUI Entries available
init:
Deleting: (file name)\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: (file name)\build\built-jar.properties
Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        code size and wider device support
Compiling 3 source files to (file name)\build\tmp
(file name)\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:42: error:  expected
        infoToBeSent.
(file name)\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:42: error: not a statement
        infoToBeSent.
(file name)\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:46: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
3 errors
(file name)\build.xml:50: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
"

What does it mean?

Comment: What code is on line 42 and 46 of your StateMachine.java?

Comment: I uploaded the screen with the code here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8LWWcoHy7-nTWVicnlDTVlpMHc/view?usp=sharing

on line 42 there is the name of the hashtable and on line 46 a closed curly brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot you shared...

Firstly, it seems like `Hashtable` was not imported and not spelt correctly. Change both `HashTable` to `Hashtable` and Press Ctrl + Shift + I to fix the import.

Secondly, `infoToBeSent.` on line 42 is not a statement, so comment it out.

Lastly, I will suggest you use `Map` and `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`.

```
Map infoToBeSent = new HashMap();
```

Seems like you are new to Java (possibly programming in general), you need to understand basic Java before you can build applications using Codename One.

Comment: Thank you, I followed the first tip you gave me and it did work.